# При skewY на блоке появляются какие-то пиксели смотрите на фото

Tags: html, css

Не знаю как объяснить.В общем мне нужно наклонить блок.Делаю это с помощью skewY
Но у меня в хроме и в опере ужасные "зубчатые края".В мозиле не так заметны но так же есть.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой css код

```
.iosSliderDemo {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 500px;
  margin: 0 0 -40px 0;
  position: relative;
  background:#8412aa;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 8%;
  -moz-transform: skewY(-14deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-14deg);
  transform: skewY(-14deg); 
    -o-transform: skewY(-14deg);
}
.oo{
  background: #48B484 ;
  background-clip: content-box ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative ;
  float: left;
  -moz-transform: skewY(7deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(7deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(7deg);
  transform: skewY(7deg);
} 
.fluidHeight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  -moz-transform: skewY(7deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(7deg);
  transform: skewY(7deg); 
    -o-transform: skewY(7deg);
}
```

Что делать?Прикол в том что на ноутбуке в хроме у меня все нормально отображает.Версии хрома одинаковые

Comment: `translateZ(0) ` еще принудительно включает gpu

Answer (score 0):

Добавил box-shadow и сгладило края